# facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph API.
If i send a comment : "Hey Man + you are kul & V"

Its printing as Hey Man you are kul.

- and & are not priting as well as contents after V.

Kindly provide ur support to solve this issue.

Comment: Please give us your code, or at least the part that sends/prints text.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to encode your message since it thinks the data after the & is an additional parameter. I think the + get's translated as a space too. You didn't specify your language, but in PHP you could wrap the message in urlencode(). As the previous comment mentioned, source would make this easier...